# Approximating the probability distribution of a sum of random variables.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, approximation-theory

The hint is supposed to set me on track and I've rearranged to get $Y=\sum X_i$ but I don't see how to approximate the probability distribution. Similar questions on this site suggest the convolution of the PDF's of the variables but we haven't covered that in my course.

Q. The times that a cashier spends processing each person’s transaction are independent and identically distributed random variables with a mean of $\mu$ and a variance of $\sigma^2.$ Thus, if $X_i$ is the processing time for each transaction, $\operatorname{E}(X_i)= \mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)= \sigma^2.$ Let $Y$ be the total processing time for 100 orders:
$Y = X_1 +X_2 + \dots +X_{100}.$

(a)What is the approximate probability distribution of $Y,$ the total processing time of 100 orders? Hint: $Y =100\bar X,$ where $\bar X = \frac 1 {100} \sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i$ is the sample mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Central Limit Theorem. (I'm guessing you must have studied it recently.)

The sum (or mean) of your 100 iid random variables should be nearly normal, unless the distribution of each of them is very highly skewed. (You can't do a convolution because you're not given the distribution of each $X_i.$)

Also, $E(Y) = 100\mu$ and $Var(Y) = 100\sigma^2.$

Comment: so far I've found z as a function of Y, so that it converges to a normal distribution which has formula z=(1/root(n))∑(i=1, n)(Xi-μ)/σ. Is this what I'm after and if so which mean and variance do I use?

Comment: or am i after the x_n(t) where such and such approaches e^-0.5t^2 as n approaches infinity?

Comment: As I read the question, you want the approximate distribution of $Y,$ which is normal. If you understand how to get the last line of my Answer, then you know the mean and variance of that normal distribution. If not, please highlight your difficulty, and maybe someone can help. (Perhaps the confusion might arise if your text states the CLT in terms of $\bar X = Y/n.$)

Comment: So I take it that the sum Y is approximately normal since we have a large number of samples and hence has mean=n*mu and variance=n*sigma^2 where our sample size n=100, which gives me the last line of your answer. 
So since we established that its a normal distribution do I just use the PDF for a normal distribution and sub the values for E(Y) and Var(Y)?

Comment: Not sure the exact format required for your course.